# Simple circuit to sense current drop and apply current to a separate circuit? Trouble with backup dashcam triggering from taillight

Tags: current, automotive

Sorry I have very little knowledge of EE but I feel like there must be a simple solution to this.  I purchased a mirror dashcam with backup camera function.  Backup camera is supposed to be triggered by reverse taillight.  Instructions say to connect red sensing wire to the hot wire of the taillight.  Thus the backup camera is triggered whenever the taillight comes on.  I did as instructed but the reverse cam comes on and stays on regardless of what gear the car is in.  I wondered if there was some voltage still in the wire, enough to keep the backup cam triggered.  In desperation I tried connecting to the ground wire (It's actually labeled GND).  Strangely now the backup cam feature engages when in drive but goes back to normal function when in reverse.  So is the wire sensing voltage in the GND when the taillight is off?  Is this how Ford taillights are designed to work?[image: taillight splice]  Anyway since it works wrong connected to the wrong wire but it works Perfectly wrong, I was wondering if there was a way to setup a separate circuit that would do the inverse of whatever's going on with that GND wire.  Since the logic is reversed is there a way to reverse that back without affecting the taillight circuit?
The manual seems to describe a circuit for a completely different problem, but I can't make heads or tails of it:
[image]
The car is a 2003 Ford Escape, and the dashcam is a CHICOM V21 1080p Mirror Dash.  Their tech support is telling me to box it back up and get a full refund, but it's a great camera and would be a huge waste to return it.

Comment: automotive lamps can be Ground switched or supply switched , where your CAM appears to be inverted for sensing. this is a logic function that is a simple voltage logic  inversion with a transistor and 2 resistors as one way to do it on a per board or possible Adafruit board

Comment: get yourself a voltmeter and determine what voltages are on the two wires when in forward drive and when in reverse drive ..... measure the voltage between frame and the wire ..... add the results to your question  ......... one more thing, are you absolutely certain that is a reverse lamp in the picture?

Comment: Ok I got a voltmeter.  I am certain that I am connecting to the proper taillight.
Neutral:
-Red "Major" wire: 14.5V
-Black "GRD" wire: 14.5V
Reverse:
-Red "Major" wire: 13.8V
-Black "GRD" wire: 2.0V

Comment: I recorded a video: https://youtu.be/WY0fTG3SZ4s

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I googled "simple voltage logic inversion" and got some promising results.  But I'm not sure where to start on building this, such as what the resistance needs to be etc.  Any direction would be appreciated.  Is there a Fiverr for Electrical Engineers? lol